# How to set Cron Quartz trigger every two weeks on Sunday?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

How to set Cron Quartz trigger every two weeks on Sunday?

I've been looking everywhere, but couldn't find any good answer for this. The the quartz website they show the simple trigger that can do this http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/BiWeeklyTrigger.html However I couldn't find a cron expression that would do this

Comment: That question does not have a wrong and not accepted answer.

Comment: Why are you looking for a Cron? Wont the simpleTrigger work for your use case? As the link you posted states, cron will restart count after each month. Anyways curious to see if its possible at all..